# React passing two arguments function to onContextMenu event

Tags: reactjs

I've got a problem with passing a function to "onContextMenu" event. I want to pass the event and argument, but when I try to do this I receive an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'preventDefault' of undefined
```

Here is my part of the code. I pass the function in the div at the end of the code.

```
    handleContextMenu(event, id){
        event.preventDefault()
        console.log(id)
        //this.setActiveNode(id)
        this.setState({showContextMenu: true, left: event.clientX, top: event.clientY})

    }

    renderSubNodes(subNodes) {
        const {activeNode} = this.state
        return (
          <ul>
            {subNodes.map((node) => (
                <React.Fragment>
                    <li>
                        <div onContextMenu={() => this.handleContextMenu(this, node.id)}
```

How to do this properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must know js closure. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures)

```js
// 1. HoF

function handleContextMenu(id){
  return function(event) {

  }
}

<div onContextMenu={this.handleContextMenu(node.id)} />


// 2. Just use dom event
// If onContextMenu has event args.

<div onContextMenu={(event) => this.handleContextMenu(event, node.id)} />
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the event to `handleContextMenu` and not a reference to `this` as `this` will refer to the instance of class component. The event is provided as a callback to onContextMenu and you can pass it on to the handleContextMenu component like below

```
<div onContextMenu={(event) => this.handleContextMenu(event, node.id)}
```